# I am attempting to collect <td>elements using beautifulsoup. The page source in Firefox shows about 150 elements. Beautifulsoup only finds 1. 1

Tags: beautifulsoup

```
def get_fy(ticker):
    global retry
    # print ( "get_fy processing", ticker, ", retry =", retry )
    try:

        # ksButton[0].click()
        k1 = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"
        k2 = "/key-statistics?p="
        path = k1+ticker+k2+ticker
        print(path)
        #r = urlopen(k1+ticker+k2+ticker)
        r = requests.get(path)
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html5lib")
        kselements = bsObj.findAll("td")
        print ( "found",len(kselements),"td elements for ticker",ticker)
        if len(kselements) > 50:
            for kse in kselements: print ( "kse: "+kse.text )
            return True
        else:
            print("too few ks elenents,", len(kselements))
            for kse in kselements: print ( "kse: "+kse.text )
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably they're added after the page load using javascript. You can't do that with requests. Use a headless browser, like Selenium.

Comment: While your answer is probably correct, I think this should have been a comment. Or at least, provide an example with using `Selenium`.